# Don't understand errors on HelloWorld in VS when included std_lib from Stroustrup's book

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I included std_lib from Stroustrup's web-site
My code is:

```
#include "c:\Users\theresmineusername\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

So I got 2 errors:

```
1. E1574    статическое объявление не удалось по причине "<hash_map> is deprecated and will be REMOVED. Please use <unordered_map>. You can define _SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS to acknowledge that you have received this warning."   ConsoleApplication2 c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.24930\include\hash_map

2. C2338    <hash_map> is deprecated and will be REMOVED. Please use <unordered_map>. You can define _SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS to acknowledge that you have received this warning.  ConsoleApplication2 c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\community\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.24930\include\hash_map
```

From the beginning of book there using "std_lib_facilities.h" and in everything but pathway of this std_lib my code is equivalent to the book. Can someone explain what it mean? Can's go next through the book with it.

Comment: 1.) Copy and paste the errors into the question as **text**. Do not use screenshots for error messages. 2.) I don't think Stroustrup teaches incorrect header usage. You must use `#include <iostream>`, and then say `std::cout` instead of `cout`.

Comment: On closer inspection, I see that Stroustrup indeed does use such a horrible header file in his book, including an ugly `using namespace std;`. That's a very strange teaching style, because it teaches you a lot of bad habits you must later unlearn.

Comment: @christian-hackl got it! Updated question. In the beginning of book he uses his own header.

Comment: Check the second message *"You can define _SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS to acknowledge that you have received this warning."*

Comment: @ChristianHackl that helper header is used only in the beginning chapters to make the starting easier. Once you get familiar with the basics, that header is no longer used. The teaching style won't look strange if you read it further.

Comment: @taskinoor: I understand Stroustrup's idea, but I strongly disagree with it.

Comment: @ChristianHackl disagreeing with his style is completely fine.

Comment: I've removed my close vote and turned my downvote into an upvote, because it's now a fair question for a beginner and accurately describes a problem which many beginners may experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std_lib_facilities.h` is a header file written by Stroustrup himself which can be [downloaded from www.stroustrup.com](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h). It is ***not* a standard C++ header** but apparently reflects Stroustrup's idea of hiding even the simplest complexities of the language from total beginners in their first few weeks.

As the header file itself says:

> This header is primarily used so that you don't have  to understand
>   every concept all at once.

I *personally* think that this is a very bad idea, with all due respect for Bjarne Stroustrup who is a greater genius than I could ever aspire to be.

The header file is full of things considered bad programming style (especially `using namespace std;`, which should *never* be used at global scope in a header file, or deriving from standard container classes). It also caters to outdated compilers which may not yet support certain "newer" features of C++ correctly, using a lot of ugly preprocessor directives.

It seems that the header file itself is quite outdated already (the one I linked to is 7 years old), and I'm not sure if Stroustrup ever updated it.

One of the preprocessor directives makes your compiler incorrectly include `<hash_map>`, when it should be `<unordered_map>`. Of course, that's absurd, because your program just wants to print a hello world message and is not even interested in hash maps.

Here's how your program should look like in **correct** C++:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

(Note that the `return 0;` is optional in `main`.)

If, however, you want to keep going with the `std_lib_facilities.h` learning aid provided by Stroustrup which you have to unlearn in a few weeks anyway, then do what the error message itself says: define `_SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS`.

The quickest way to do so is with a `#define` in the source code:

```
#define _SILENCE_STDEXT_HASH_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS
#include "c:\Users\theresmineusername\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

When the times comes, throw it away together with the `#include` for `std_lib_facilities.h`.

Comment: Nitpick: `return 0;` from `main()` isn't required.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I say so directly below the code snippet! :)

Comment: Ah, didn't spot at 1st glance.

Comment: It's work. Thank you. It was still an error while i added `#define...` after `#include..`, but in this case (conversely) everything is fine.

Answer (score 3):

The idiomatic way to write this in c++ is:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

The header file from the book examples shouldn't be used.

Comment: It's true. But in this case, generally lost a specific point in the reading because it is used in a large part of the Stroustrup's book.