# Terminal won't run the newly compiled file, always running the previously compiled file

Tags: c++, terminal, compilation

EDIT: The problem is due to an error in the book, since it is a bit old now.

I am writing a simple program in C++, and when I recompile my code, terminal runs the previous version of my compiled file. The name of my source code is **exercise.cpp**. Here is my source code before refactoring it:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter your first name and age\n";
    string first_name;
    int age;
    cin >> first_name;
    cin >> age;
    cout << "Hello, " << first_name << " (age " << age << ")\n";
}
```

And here is the slightly refactored version:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    cout<<"Please enter your first name and age:\n";
    string first_name = "???";
    int age = -1;
    cin>>first_name>>age;
    cout<<"Hello, "<<first_name<<" (age "<<age<<")\n";
}
```

When I compile the refactored file, and run **./exercise** in terminal, it gives the output of the first source code. For example, if your run the first compiled file and your input is "22 Mark" in the first source code, the output is "Hello, 22 (age 0)". (Or instead of 0 whatever garbage value was in the memory). If you run the newly compiled file and your input is the same, I expect the output to be "Hello, 22 (age -1)" since I have already initialized my variable in the refactored code. However, the output is still "Hello, 22 (age 0)". What causes this, and how can I fix it?

PS. I use Visual Studio Code as my editor and GNU compiler as my compiler.

Comment: Look at the time stamp on the executable. Verify that the new code was built. Perhaps disable your antivirus. In short you likely need to debug the situation before getting help so that you can answer the what causes this question. Also check the build output for error messages. Perhaps your previous executable was still running so the build failed.

Comment: I checked the time stamp and verified that the new code has been built. I also don't get any error messages in my both build outputs. The task is built successfully. @drescherjm

Comment: As a double-check, add `std::cout << "Compiled " << __DATE__ << " " << __TIME__ << std::endl;` before you do the input to verify the date & time the object files in the running binary were actually compiled.

Comment: I checked it, and it compiles without any problems. I also checked it by changing the first output, and it changes every time I compile. The only problem is that the age variable won't output -1 when given a non-integer value. I still don't know the reason behind it. @JohnD

Answer (score 0):

Try to include  directive instead of std_lib_facilities.h as it might cause errors as mentioned in the accepted answer in the attached link:
["std_lib_facilities.h" showing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51313578/std-lib-facilities-h-showing-error)

Comment: The problem is, no errors occur while compiling and running the program. Everything goes smoothly except that I can’t run the last executable for some reason. It keeps running the previous one.

Comment: You're expecting the output to be -1 however you are asking the user to enter the value of age if you want to print -1 then remove age from the cin statement.