# C++ std_lib_facilities.h file in VSCode (Mac) 2020

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I've just started learning how to program. I set up VSCode on my Mac and the C/C++ extension. I wrote the helloworld program from Stroustrup's Programming and Principles book. I put the std_lib_facilities.h file in the same folder as my helloworld.cpp file. Still I get the error message: #include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit.

Why am I still getting the error? The book says all I need is to have the std_lib_facilities.h.txt file in the same directory as my .cpp program. They're in the same folder, so why am I getting this error?

My code:

```
#include "std_lib_facilites.h"

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World \n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is c++ std\_lib\_facilities.h still used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45877104/is-c-std-lib-facilities-h-still-used)

Comment: thanks, all I did now for it to get the text file was type: #include "full directory path", i.e:
#include "Users/Venkat/project/helloworld/std_lib_facilites.h"

Comment: Thanks Gino, from one of the answers/comments from the question you linked, turns out I had to download a new version of the std_lib_facilities file and turns out I have to write the .txt after the .h too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have a typo in the filename.

> `#include "std_lib_facilites.h"`

It should be `std_lib_facilities.h` ([source 1](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/std_lib_facilities.h), [source 2](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BjarneStroustrup/Programming-_Principles_and_Practice_Using_Cpp/master/std_lib_facilities.h)).
And make sure to save it as `.h`.

Second, you can configure a *.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json* file to specify the path to the header files. See the VS Code docs for the [JSON schema reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference).

1. Open the Command Palette
2. Select "C/C++: Edit Configurations (JSON)"
3. Set the `includePath`

```
 "configurations": [
     {
         "name": "Mac",
         "includePath": [
             "${workspaceFolder}/**",
             "/path/to/headers"
         ],
         ...
     }
 ],
```

By default it already has `"${workspaceFolder}/**"` which should search for header files in your workspace (and its sub-folders). But you can also specify paths to other folders.